# Simple MP3 player with ability to play files randomly and global keyboard shortcuts

Tags: windows, software-rec, winamp, mp3-player

I yearn for the good old days when WinAmp was the only game in town. Unfortunately, WinAmp has had to add feature to keep up with the competition.

I want a very simple player for Windows where I can

- add/drag files
- play them randomly AND
- have a hotkey to skip to the next (random) track, even with the player in the background

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### [foobar2k](http://www.foobar2000.org/)

[image: foobar2k]

- Simple interface, just add and play
- Play random tracks (random order vs. shuffle order, [FAQ here](http://www.foobar2000.org/FAQ#random_shuffle_playback_order))
- Global keyboard shortcuts ([documentation here](http://wiki.hydrogenaudio.org/index.php?title=Foobar2000:Preferences:General:Keyboard_Shortcuts))